# Trapezoid Rule in C, wrong answer

Tags: c, numerical-integration

I want to implement the trapezoid tule in C for a project. I am using an example from the book [Numerical Recipes in C](https://www2.units.it/ipl/students_area/imm2/files/Numerical_Recipes.pdf) on page 137. I first just want to copy the code, play around with it for different functions, and then later try to understand every line. However, my program doesn't output the right answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
float h(float x)
{ 
    return sin(x);
}
float trapzd(float (*func)(float), float a, float b, int n)
{   float x, tnm, sum, del; 
    static float s;
    int it, j;
    if (n == 1) {
        return (s=0.5*(b-a)*(h(a)+h(b)));


    } 
    else
    {
        for (it=1,j=1;j<n-1;j++) it <<=1;
        tnm=it;
        del=(b-a)/tnm;
        x=a+0.5*del;
        for(sum=0.0,j=1; j<=it; j++, x+=del) sum+=h(x);
        s=0.5*(s+(b-a)*sum/tnm);   

        return s;
    }

}
int main(void)
{   
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
    {
    printf("With n = %d, the approximation is %g.\n", i, trapzd(h,0,1,i));
    }

}
```

So I want to integrate `sin(x)` from `0` to `1` which should equal about `0.45` but the program outputs `0.000002`. If I use `exp(x)`, the output is `0.50000` instead of approximately `1.7`. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Yes I copy and paced it here. Edit: I just changed it and it atleast outputs 0.229 now, a better value! Edit2: Also, if I increase the number of steps (variable n) to lets say 100, it outputs -nan.

Comment: Ah yes, now it outputs the right results. Seems to be an error in the book then. Still, I don't understand why it outputs -nan if I increase the number of steps to 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The routine `trapzd` is designed to be called iteratively to approach the correct answer. You cannot call it directly with 20 for the parameter `n`. You must first call it with 1, then 2, then 3, and so on.

For example, using the original code in *Numerical Recipes* (remove the `printf` statements you inserted in `trapzd`):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; ++i)
    printf("With n = %d, the approximation is %g.\n", i, trapzd(h, 0, 1, i));
```

Also, as [Mark Dickinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/270986/mark-dickinson) pointed out, `x=+del` should be `x+=del`.

The source in *Numerical Recipes* is **horrible** design. The function has internal state, in the static object `s`. Maybe there is some pedagogical excuse for that, but such code should **never** be used in real-world code. (A proper method to implement a routine that does iterative refinement would be to return state information to the caller, which they could pass back in a future call.)

Instructions for calling the function are in the reference you cited:

> When called with n=1, the routine returns the crudest estimate of [the integral of f(*x*) d*x* from *a* to *b*]. Subsequent calls with n=2,3,... a (in that sequential order) will improve the accuracy by adding 2<sup>n-2</sup> additional interior points.

Do not blindly copy source code without understanding it.

Comment: Thank you. What would call iteratively mean? Could you post an example please?

Comment: @Eren: In this context, iteratively refers to calling the function **first** with `trapzd(h, 0, 1, 1)`, then with `trapzd(h, 0, 1, 2)`, then `trapzd(h, 0, 1, 3)`,… You cannot simply call it with 20; you must get there incrementally. I added code to show that.

Comment: Hi and thank you very much again. I understand what it means now, but If I do that, the output increases. For example for  i <=10 the output is:        With n = 1, the ... is 0.420735, With n = 2, .... is 0.900161, With n= 3, .... is 1.36468 etc. With more "steps" shouldn't it get closer to the "true" value of around 0.4596 (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+sin(x)+from+0+to+1)?

Comment: I Edited the code above to the one I use now. I removed the printf statements in trapzd, and inserted the for loop int main(void) and instead of x=+del i corrected it to x+=del

Comment: @Eren: When I compile and execute that code, the last line is “With n = 10, the approximation is 0.459697.” That would seem to be the desired behavior.

Comment: Yes don't know what I changed, but now it works for me aswell. I'll try to understand the code now. Thank you so much!